# Bit based division property

Tags: cryptanalysis, block-cipher

Bit based division property is a great method of Integral attack on block ciphers, which was invented by Y. Todo.
According to the paper [*Bit-Based Division Property and Application to Simon Family*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/285.pdf) (in [proceedings of FSE 2016](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-52993-5_18)), how does the set $[11110000]$ will propagate bellow sets?

$[11110000]\rightarrow [11110000]; [11000010]; [01110010];$
$[01100001] \rightarrow [01100001]; [01000011];$
$[10110001]\rightarrow  [10110001]; [10000011]; [00110011]$

Furthermore, what means the state "Finally, since the round key is XORed with the right half, the parity of $\pi_{[00001111]}(x)$
for all $x\in X$ becomes unknown"